# How to get the debugging target information for a node.js process in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I would like to write a Chrome extension that uses the `chrome.debugger API` to attach to a node.js process started with "--inspect", in order to set breakpoints and control execution of the node process. I consulted the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger), and it appears I would use the API `chrome.debugger.attach` in order to attach the debugging client to the node.js process. The `attach` API accepts as an argument the targetId of the debugging target to attach. My question is, how can I find the targetId of the Node.js process, which I can pass to `attach`?

I attempted to find the node.js debugging target using the `chrome.debugger.getTargets` API, but the resulting array of targetInfo did not include the node.js process. The node.js process **does** appear in chrome://inspect, and I am able to use chrome devtools to inspect the process. I'm wondering if the node.js process does not appear in the targetInfo results because the node.js process is a remote debugging target, whereas all other results in this array were local debugging targets.

I would appreciate any insight into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at how google have retrieved the remote source's.  eg. Use inspector inside the `chrome://inspect`.

There is a javascript function called `populateRemoteTargets` inside `inspect.js`

On my machine the data parameter been sent is ->

```
{
  "adbConnected": true,
  "adbModel": "Remote Target",
  "adbSerial": "localhost",
  "browsers": [
    {
      "adbBrowserChromeVersion": 0,
      "adbBrowserName": "Target",
      "adbBrowserUser": "",
      "adbBrowserVersion": "",
      "id": "localhost:9222",
      "pages": [],
      "source": "remote"
    },
    {
      "adbBrowserChromeVersion": 0,
      "adbBrowserName": "Target",
      "adbBrowserUser": "",
      "adbBrowserVersion": "",
      "id": "localhost:9229",
      "pages": [],
      "source": "remote"
    }
  ],
  "id": "device:localhost"
}
```

Not sure were google store this list, but's it obviously what's stored in the configure dialog.  There may be a way to get this data, not sure.  If not, you could maybe maintain the list yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like populateRemoteTargets is receiving data populated and passed in from C++. I traced it, and the data structure is populated by devtools_device_discovery.cc here: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/devtools/device/devtools_device_discovery.cc?gsn=CreateForAdb&l=568 Whereas chrome.debugger.getTargets is implemented in shared_worker_devtools_manager.h: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/devtools/shared_worker_devtools_manager.h?gsn=AddAllAgentHosts&l=51 Maybe these are two competing implementations for querying targets?

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=412651&q=gettargets&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified